# inner html change font size on all html tags

Tags: angular, innerhtml

```html
<div>
<p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; text-align: center; font-size: 18pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif; font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">Hello test</span></p>
<p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;"><span style="font-size: 8.0pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify; margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;"><span style="font-size: 6.5pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">Testing font<strong></p>
</div>
```

I have an innerhtml like the above one is there a way i can change all the font size without using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replace method.

e.g.

```
      let html = `<div><p style="margin: 0in 0in 0.0001pt;      
                    text-align: center; font-size: 18pt; font-family: 
                   'Times New Roman ...... </div>` 
      let newHtml = html.replace('font-size: 18pt', 'font-size: 
                    '20pt');
```

Then render newHtml in view page.

```
     <div [innerHtml]="newHtml"> </div>
```